# How to split quoted strings in Bash?

Tags: bash, awk, split

There are few [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash) with good answers on how to split strings in Bash scripts by a given separator.

My problem is that I got a file with space separated strings, which **may** be quoted, e.g.

```
foo bar "foo bar baz" baz
```

which I'd like into the 4 values `foo`, `bar`, `foo bar baz` and `baz`.

How do I split these inputs into a Bash array by respecting the quotes?

Comment: The question is a bit terse. Is is just a line of strings or does the strings span multiple lines? Also, what have you done so far to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bash` shell by default does not provide a multi character `IFS` support to delimit, but since it is a file we are dealing with, we can use `GNU Awk` with its support for FPAT to define how to handle each word we are dealing with.

From the GNU Awk man page under [Defining Fields by Content](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html)

> Normally, when using `FS`, `gawk` defines the fields as the parts of the record that occur in between each field separator. In other words, `FS` defines what a field is not, instead of what a field is. However, there are times when you really want to define the fields by what they are, and not by what they are not.

The latter part is when we need to use `FPAT`, for your requirement with space separated strings and strings within double-quotes, we define a pattern as below, meaning anything that is not a space (or) containing inside double-quote but not a double-quote.

```
FPAT = "([^[:space:]]+)|("[^"]+")"
```

But to write it as string into `Awk`, you need to escape the double-quotes above,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT = "([^[:space:]]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' myFile
```

This will print each word of your input in question in a separate line as below,

```
foo
bar
"foo bar baz"
baz
```

From here, to store in a `bash` context all you need is process-substitution and `mapfile` command,

```
mapfile -t newArray < <(awk 'BEGIN{FPAT = "([^[:space:]]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' myFile)
```

And then you can print the array as

```
declare -p newArray
```

(or) print it explicitly

```
for item in "${newArray[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$item"
done
```

Comment: you may omit parenthesis `(<pattern1>)|(<pattern2>)` in `FPAT`

Comment: excactly what I needed - and especially thank you for the great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If it's only one item with double quote, you can use this sed

```
sed 's/ /\n/g;h;s/[^"]*"\([^"]*\).*/"\1/;s/\n/ /g;x;G;s/\([^"]*\)"\([^"]*\)\("[^"]*\)\n\(".*\)/\1\4\3/' infile
```

If it's one or more, you can use this awk

```
awk -F'"' -vOFS='"' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if((i%2)==1){gsub(" ","\n",$i)}}1' infile
```